# Playing higher A and B

Tags: guitar

I just started playing guitar yesterday.  I have learned how to play notes like this, going from lower to higher notes:

- **A -  hold down 3rd string on 2nd fret and pluck it**
- **B - just pluck 2nd string**
- **C - hold down 2nd string on 1st fret and pluck it**
- **D - hold down 2nd string on 3rd fret and pluck it**
- **E - just pluck 1st string**
- **F - hold down 1st string on 1st fret and pluck it**
- **G - hold down 1st string on 3rd fret and pluck it**

Everything works but now I have to play this:

G-A-B-G and I need that A and B to be higher than G (which I have learned to play).  Can someone help me which strings I need to hold down to play A and B above G?

Comment: @cornbreadninja : i think because I was not familiar with guitar terms.

Comment: I hope not.  I edited it before @Alex Basson to make them more guitar-like.  I didn't do it (I suppose that's obvious) and I doubt Alex did.  :\

Comment: Nope, wasn't me.  And I'll just take this opportunity to repeat what many others have already said on SE sites: By all means, downvote if that's how you feel, but then please also write a comment with a brief, preferably constructive explanation.  That way the poster has an opportunity to improve the quality of his/her post and thus improve the site in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible solutions, but which one is best depends on what exactly you want.  Here are two possibilities:

1. The easiest solution is to play the G *below* the A and the B you've learned already.  This G is the open third string---in other words, just pluck the third string.  Then play the A and the B as you've shown above.
2. If, instead, you want the G to be the one you've indicated (i.e. the G on the first string, 3rd fret), then you should play the A on the first string, 5th fret and the B on the first string, 7th fret.

For a beginning guitarist such as yourself, I definitely recommend the first solution unless you have a specific reason why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose the higher voicing that @Alex describes, there are at least two good ways to finger it.

You can *jump to second position* and fret the A with your index finger and the B with your ring finger.

Or you can fret the notes on the E string in a more "stretchy" manner: you fret the F with your index (as normal), then you *stretch* and fret the G with your middle finger, *roll* the middle finger and *stretch* to fret the A with your pinky, then you slide your whole hand up and catch the B still with the pinky; going back down, you fret the A with the middle finger, then slide your hand back to get the G still with the middle finger.

For that G-A-B-G run, I'd finger that as index-middle-pinky-index.